# My form is not getting validated in Zend Famework. Why?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-rest

I am creating a rest Module for album module of zf2
My Code Snippet for create method :

```
public function create($data) {
$form=new AlbumForm();
$album = new Album();
$form->setInputFilter($album->getInputFilter());
$form->setData($data);

if ($form->isValid()) {
$album->exchangeArray($form->getData());
$id = $this->getAlbumTable()->saveAlbum($album);
return new JsonModel(array(
        'data' => $this->get($id),
    ));
}
```

All the functionalities like update,select all,delete are working properly but insertion is not working. 
I have selected post method through my Advanced rest client application and passing arguments like title=some&artist=someone its not validating form.

The form having values like
id  Auto-incremented,
artist varchar,
title varchar,

Please Help for this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just got the answer that you have to add this lines to the top of the create method.

```
if (empty($data['id'])) $data['id'] = 0;
```

Its working properly.